# Algorithm to fill a closed path composed of lines and quadratic bezier curves

Tags: math, bezier, rasterizing

I'm experimenting with a software rasterizer, and I've been trying to figure out how to fill a closed 'path'. What I've seen so far involves either turning the path into a closed poly-line, or finding all the `x` values, and then using matching [pairs](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon_fill/).

With the second method, I would need to find value `t` where `y = pixel_row`, which requires rearranging the `y` component of the bezier function to `t`, and then using that to calculate the `x` values. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do so.

My question is thus: Are these the only two methods? And is their a more optimal method? For said optimal method; what are the mechanics (maths) behind it?

Comment: There's the opposite concept: instead of filling "from one point to the other", you create a rect that fits the bounding box, fill it, then blank (either mark as invalid, or set a=0, etc) all the curve pixels. Then in a final linear pass, you blank all pixels from the edge of the box until it hits a blanked pixel, which marks your "to remove/to preserve" boundary. Then you scan for the next blanked pixel on the same row or column, and remove everything after that until the edge, and you do that for all rows or columns.

Comment: Huh, that's interesting. Wouldn't that require more memory accesses though? You're setting all the pixels at least once, and a lot of them again afterwards.

Comment: depends entirely on what does the fill. Naively you're running linear passes for the initial fill (w x h), the curve LUT (lut.length), and then the invalidation, but you can do often do the initial fill as a single operation (using a `memcopy` or something), or even as part of the vector/array init, so you're left with O(w x h x lut.length). The trick is making sure your LUT is not too small (but that's a problem you'll have irrespective of whether you're doing fills or not)

Comment: You refer to the length of the buffer as `lut`, right? Also, how do you determine where each `x` value is for quadratic bezier curves? That's the thing that has me stumped.

Comment: the pixel array is a linear data structure of width x height for monochrome, or width x height x channel count for coloured. But here's the nice part: you don't need colour, you can actually use your monochrome fill as a mask to *any* colour or texture, and the GPU does the rest. The LUT is your curve's coordinate lookup table, ideally of the kind where each successive element gives you an (x,y) exactly one pixel distance at the scale you're working on.

Comment: Okay, I think there's some miscommunication here. I have a path, stored as `[MOVE, int2, QUAD, int2, int2, LINE, int2]` where each command continues off the last position, and I want to rasterize this to an image in memory. My problem is in generating the `x` components of the curve, such that I can retrieve them through the `y` component (the scan line), as well as if there are any more efficient methods to do so. You sort of answered the second part, but you still haven't told me how to generate the LUT so that it maps to each scan line.

Comment: Right, so for this way to fill (not others) you would rasterize that path to a "continuous" sequence of pixel coordinates. Rather than "generating x that can be looked up with y", you get an array of x/y pairs for which all you know is that the next coordinate is exactly 1 pixel away (at most), and then you run through that once, marking each x/y pair found in your bounding map as invalid. Generating the LUT is really just a matter of "straight lines are trivial" and "bezier curves require evaluating the bezier function", which is a fairly simple function to work with

Comment: (more details that you'll ever need for this on bezier curves [here](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo)

Comment: One thing I can recommend is "look at other people's source code". Have a look at how Java2D does path filling, as well as how paper.js does it, and that'll set you up with a good number of ideas that will let you either start implementing, or at least give you the right terms to google with.